# MQTT Paho C/C++ Client for Windows using Eclipse + MinGW

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse, mqtt, pahocpp

I am trying to use MQTT Poho C/C++ Client on Windows using Eclipse CDT and MinGW.
On Windows 10 I have installed Eclipse Neon and MinGW latest version with POSIX Thread Support.

**Issue with MQTT Paho C++:**

- I have download the [MQTT Paho Client C++ Source](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.cpp) and also dependent C Library + headers
- I have created a Eclipse CDT MinGW project and trying to build the sample application using C++ Paho
- I am not able to build the code as I am getting compilation error for "std::mutex" `'mutex' is not a member of 'std'`, I tried to resolve it by googling but with no luck
- As per one of the solutions I have also uninstalled MinGW which I have previously installed with `pthread Win32` support and installed it again with `pthread POSIX` support.
- I am also not able to find Paho C++ Pre-built libraries

**Issue with MQTT Paho C Pre-built libraries:**

- I have download the [Paho Pre-built C Library + headers](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/iot.paho/downloads) for Windows
- The zip file has `.lib` `.dll` `.h` and some samples
- Again I have created a test project in Eclipse and included headers and libraries
- Also configured the library path
- It compiles correctly but linker hits the error and not able to find functions defined in .dll/.lib files
- I checked rechecked everything but not sure about the issue
- Do I need to use the DLL files provided with the library? I have not used them. I have tried to copy them in the `Path` and also in the same location as `.lib` but of no use
- Also did google on how to use `.dll` with `Eclipse CDT MinGW` but no luck. :(

Let me know if anyone has tried to use Eclipse Paho C/C++ Source/Library With Windows Eclipse CDT MinGW.
Any possible solution to these issues will help.

Comment: Did you try simply  `#include <mutex>`?

Comment: @JesperJuhl The sample code that is provided with the Library contains `#include <mutex>` so I don't need to include it again.